# XML Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, open-source

I just start learning to write web services yesterday, kinda fascinating. I created an XML web service, i most program on my Linux box, I want to use the java language or some other language to access this web service. Can you direct me to any tutorial that show how to access the .net web services from another programming language.

Comment: One Tip:  Avoid exposing ADO.NET data structures (datatables, datasets) over your webservices.  While technically they are SOAP/XML they won't find too many other languages which will implement their features--basic XML structures are much more language agnostic and cover most uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web services should be language/platform independent. That is one of the pillars. So you should access web service written in .net like any other web service. The implementation details shouldn't be visible for customer of the web service.

Comment: Yeah i know that. What i'm asking is if you can direct me to some tutorials for implementation and calling the web service from other lanaguage

Comment: Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/WSfromJava.aspx It's a little old though.

Comment: BTW, if you are starting with web services in .net go with WCF if possible. XML ASP.NET web services are history.

Answer (score 1):

For an example, you can try [Jquery.get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype):

> *Load a remote page using an HTTP GET request.*
>
> This is an easy way to send a simple GET request to a server without having to use the more complex $.ajax function. It allows a single callback function to be specified that will be executed when the request is complete (and only if the response has a successful response code). If you need to have both error and success callbacks, you may want to use $.ajax.

If your web service provides an `XML` response, set the `type` argument to "xml".
Use a `Javascript` snippet from a Jquery example.

A very simple *JQuery* snippet [(from a tutorial)](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax), using `Jquery.post()`, which calls the server with an argument (`t`) and displays the content of the reply as a text alert:

```
 $.post("test2.php",{content: t},function(txt){
   alert(txt);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To consume an XML service, use Java, JavaScript, Ruby, Perl, Python, whatever. You just need to be able to read HTTP streams and parse the XML.

Comment: an example or tutorial would be nice :)

Comment: Which language do you want to use? Google: SOME_LANGUAGE parse xml.

Answer (score 0):

Java comes with some [web-service APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/webservices.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can try using the very good frameworks Axis2 or Spring-WS:

http://axis2.apache.org

hxxp://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/

You will find good documentation on the project sites and all over the web.